# SSRS 2005 How-to: Headers for groups within groups?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

It seems pretty straight forward to get what I want. The data details display correctly but I can't get the headers to cooperate.

I have n number of clients with their activity in the report. I want the client name in the header, and then the column names below that. But I either get columns repeating before every entry or no client name.

This is what I want the reports to looks like:

```
**Client # 1**

Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
data   data   data


**Client # 2**

Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
data   data   data


**Client # n**

Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
data   data   data
```

Unfortunately what I get is this:

```
**Client # 1**

Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
Col1   Col2   Col3
data   data   data
```

OR This:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3

**Client # 1**

data   data   data
data   data   data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an extra row to the group header at the level where the client name appears (right-click on the grey property box outside the RH edge of the row and select "add row below").

Put your column headers in this row and they will repeat with the same frequency as the client name.

Comment: Yeah but the problem comes when you want to initially collapse the group header and details. The details collapse, but not the header!

Comment: Oops. Just realised you need to Toggle Visible the header just like the detail to another control, and it works! Thanks!!